# Why git pull doesn't create a commit?

Tags: git

As docs said:

> git push is git fetch followed by git merge

So why doesn't git merge create a commit with that merge?

Comment: The answer to life, the universe and everything is "fast-forward".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `git pull` create a merge commit only if needed. By default, if possible, `fast-forward` is used to do the merge. This is equivalent to use

```
git fetch
git merge --ff
```

As [doc said](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---ff):

> --ff
>
> When the merge resolves as a fast-forward, only update the branch pointer, without creating a merge commit. This is the default behavior.

Obviously, you can ensure a merge commit is always created by using

```
git pull --no-ff
```